# Modify date as per matching a attribute name value in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an array of element where a:value element can have different values in it. In case the element contains date in Zulu format i.e.: 2019-04-17T10:42:48.0135859, I need to change it to YYYY-MM-DD format. I have already come up with a solution. However, I am more interested in the matching i:type="b:dateTime" in my condition. Which means if i:type is equal to or contains b:dateTime then the XSLT will fetch the date and do the required transformation.

The input XML is:

```
<Properties
xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
<a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
<a:Key>dtDynamicModifyDate</a:Key>
<a:Value i:type="b:dateTime"
xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>2019-04-17T10:42:48.0135859</a:Value>
</a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
<a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
<a:Key>tiEnrollmentStatus</a:Key>
<a:Value i:type="b:string"
xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>Enrolled</a:Value>
</a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
<a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
<a:Key>tiNumberOfEnrollments</a:Key>
<a:Value i:type="b:int"
xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>1</a:Value>
</a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
<a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
<a:Key>dtModifyDate</a:Key>
<a:Value i:type="b:dateTime"
xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>2019-04-16T15:57:39.331-04:00</a:Value>
</a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
</Properties>
```

The transformation is available here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mC/1

Instead of this condition, I want the above condition to be checked (i:type is equal to or contains b:dateTime)

```
<xsl:when test="contains($payload/*[local-name()='Value'], '-') and contains($payload/*[local-name()='Value'], 'T') and contains($payload/*[local-name()='Value'], ':')">
```

Any pointer for the XPATH will be appreciated.

Cheers,
Sierra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression I think you are looking for is this...

```
<xsl:when test="$payload/*[local-name()='Value']/@*[name()='i:type'] ='b:dateTime'">
```

However, this would fail if the namespace prefix changed, so perhaps you should do this:

```
<xsl:when test="$payload/*[local-name()='Value']/@*[local-name()='type'] ='b:dateTime'">
```

But this could potentially not give you the right results if you had two attributes named `type` in different namespace. The only real solution is to declare the `xmlns:i` namespace in the XSLT, then you would do this:

```
<xsl:when test="$payload/*[local-name()='Value']/@i:type ='b:dateTime'">
```